# How the Chrome REST client works without setting CORS header?

Tags: google-chrome, rest

My server is set to handle CORS headers. That is by default server expects '`Origin`' header from the client requests.
But when i try with google chrome client without setting `'Origin`' header, I get the response.
How this works?

My request header;

```
GET /delete/1.0 HTTP/1.1
Authorization:  Bearer 98b42f3eee1db4bc1dc8fca8e557f13
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5555
```

My response header;

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type
Host: 127.0.0.1:5555
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 03 Oct 2014 06:45:13 GMT
Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: Looking for the same answer...

Answer (score 0):

This gets added automatically by Chrome. If you check the headers on your Server side you will see it comes added with the `Origin`.

How Chrome add it in the backend, is something Google Developers can tell.